# Recursive Dynamic Programming Solution is Too Slow

Tags: c++, algorithm, recursion, complexity-theory

I've been stuck for over an hour where I've had a correct solution to a dynamic programming problem, but it's too slow for some reason. I keep getting timeouts on test cases on hackerrank, even though I'm using C++ (I'd expect this kind of problem with Java).

[Here is the Coin Change Problem](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/coin-change)

And here is my code for the problem:

```
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

/*
    N - The amount of change that should be created.
    M - The number of elements in the C array.
    C[] - The array of possible coins to use. Coins can be reused.
    i - The index of the coin to begin with, as to not 
            repeat combinations already used.
*/
unsigned long long coinChangeCombinations(int N, int M, int C[], int i) {
    unsigned long long combinations = 0;
    for (; i < M; i++) {
        int c = C[i];
        if (N == c) {
            combinations++;
        } else if (N > c) {
            combinations += coinChangeCombinations(N - c, M, C, i);
        }
    }
    return combinations;
}

int main() {
    unsigned long long N, M;
    cin >> N;
    cin >> M;
    int C[M];
    for (int i = 0; i < M; i++) {
        int c;
        cin >> c;
        C[i] = c;
    }
    cout << coinChangeCombinations(N, M, C, 0) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Most of the discussion is focussed around the iterative solution - is iterative always faster than recursive? In this case, I see no reason for the iterative solution to be faster than the recursive. Sure, recursion will take up more memory, but that's not the issue I'm running into here.

Comment: Your solution is a simple brute force backtracking solution, and NOT dynamic programming as you state. Turning it into top-down or bottom-up dynamic programming will improve performance significantly.

Comment: @amit The sub-problems are not repeated (ie once you prove you can form X change using coins (a, b, c), you never again calculate that you can form X using (a, b, c)). Is this not dynamic programming?

It should be top-down, from the way I see it.

Comment: It is top-down, just not DP, since there is no memoization. I don't see how this avoids repeating sub-problems.

Comment: Ohh I understand, thank you.